# What am i missing? c++ errors

Tags: c++, syntax-error

So, here is the updated thread: Maybe there is white space in there that I'm not seeing?  It is the exact same error as it was before. You anyone can think of anything to try, ill do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  

// 1. Initialize Objects

    double retail = 0.0;
    double markup = 0.0;
    double wholesale = 0.00;

// 2. Input

    cout << "Hello Emily CO 127: ";

    cout << "Enter Retail Price: ";
    cin >> retail;

    cout << "Enter Mark Up Percent: ";
    cin >> markup;
// 3. Process

    wholesale = retail * (1 + markup);

    cout << " Wholesale " << wholesale << endl;

    return 0;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Try `HelloWorld` first. With any new language.

Comment: maybe your missing #include "stdafx.h"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace std;` is a declaration that introduces the identifiers from the namespace called `std` in the global scope. It is **not** the beginning of function or starting point for a block. What you're missing is your `main` function:

```
int main() // start of the program
{
    // ...
}
```

This is what your program should look like then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  

// 1. Initialize Objects

    double retail = 0.0;
    double markup = 0.0;
    double wholesale = 0.00;

// 2. Input

    cout << "Hello Emily CO 127: ";

    cout << "Enter Retail Price: ";
    cin >> retail;

    cout << "Enter Mark Up Percent: ";
    cin >> markup;
// 3. Process

    wholesale = retail * (1 + markup);

    cout << " Wholesale " << wholesale << endl;

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

You should read up more on the basics of C++, they will explain everything you need to know.